# How to access cox.zph components

Tags: r, sweave, cox-regression

I would like to use the `P` value of `cox.zph` in a Sweave document, something like this:

```
<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
campo = campos[1]
m1=coxph(Surv(TimeVar,EventVar)~Factor)
z=cox.zph(m1)
….
@
```

If I assign to an object `print(cox.zph(m1))`:

```
temp = print(cox.zph(m1))
```

I have the p value in the third component `temp[3]`, but the instruction `print(z)` outputs the results to the document, and I want only to store the `P` value in another variable, not to show the results.

I tried invisible function, but it doesn’t work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question, use `results=hide` in your list of options.

```
<<echo=FALSE,results=hide>>=
campo = campos[1]
m1=coxph(Surv(TimeVar,EventVar)~Factor)
z=cox.zph(m1)
temp = print(x)
@
```

You can then access the `temp` variable. A better solution is to pull out the parts of the `z` object you need. So in your case, this would be:

```
##z is a list
z1 = z[[1]]
```

The variable `z1` is a matrix that contains the information you need.